# How to adjust the y-axis of bar plot in R using only the barplot function

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, axis-labels

Using this example:

```
 x<-mtcars;
 barplot(x$mpg);
```

you get a graph that is a lot of barplots from (0 - 30).

My question is how can you adjust it so that the y axis is (10-30) with a split at the bottom indicating that there was data below the cut off?

Specifically, I want to do this in base R program using only the `barplot` function and not functions from **plotrix** (unlike the suggests already provided). Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want something like `barplot(table(cut(x$mpg, breaks=5)))`?

Comment: MrFlick (cool name FYI) I am wanting is to cut off the 0-9 on the y axis on the barplot. If I used ylim=(10-30) it works but then I have the rest of the barplot falling off the plot. I want to cut that off. Maybe start at 0 on the y axis and then cut, followed by bar plotting 10-30 on the y axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not recommended. It is generally considered bad practice to chop off the bottoms of bars. However, if you look at `?barplot`, it has a `ylim` argument which can be combined with `xpd = FALSE` (which turns on "clipping") to chop off the bottom of the bars.

```
barplot(mtcars$mpg, ylim = c(10, 30), xpd = FALSE)
```

Also note that you should be careful here. I followed your question and used 0 and 30 as the y-bounds, but the maximum mpg is 33.9, so I also clipped the top of the 4 bars that have values > 30.

The only way I know of to make a "split" in an axis is using `plotrix`. So, based on

> Specifically, I want to do this in base R program using only the barplot function and not functions from plotrix (unlike the suggests already provided). Is this possible?

the answer is "no, this is not possible" in the sense that I think you mean. `plotrix` certainly does it, and it uses base R functions, so you could do it however they do it, but then you might as well use `plotrix`.

You can plot on top of your barplot, perhaps a horizontal dashed line (like below) could help indicate that you're breaking the commonly accepted rules of what barplots should be:

```
abline(h = 10.2, col = "white", lwd = 2, lty = 2)
```

The resulting image is below:

[image]

**Edit:** You could use `segments` to spoof an axis break, something like this:

```
barplot(mtcars$mpg, ylim = c(10, 30), xpd = FALSE)
xbase = -1.5
xoff = 0.5
ybase = c(10.3, 10.7)
yoff = 0
segments(x0 = xbase - xoff, x1 = xbase + xoff,
         y0 = ybase-yoff, y1 = ybase + yoff, xpd = T, lwd = 2)
abline(h = mean(ybase), lwd = 2, lty = 2, col = "white")
```

As-is, this is pretty fragile, the `xbase` was adjusted by hand as it will depend on the range of your data. You could switch the barplot to `xaxs = "i"` and set `xbase = 0` for more predictability, but why not just use `plotrix` which has already done all this work for you?!

**ggplot** In comments you said you don't like the look of `ggplot`. This is easily customized, e.g.:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x, aes(y = mpg, x = id)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", fill = "gray80", width = 0.8) +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: thx gregor. I was hoping not to used plotrix or ggplot. However, looks as if I will need to. I agree that chopping the bottom off is bad. That is why I wanted to do the cut thing plotrix does. I just dont like how plotrix and ggplot present the graphs. I like the visual that the base barplot() gives. Anyways I took your answer and upvoted. Thanks alot again.

Comment: If your only aversion to ggplot is the way it looks, you just need to try out some other themes. (Though it won't make it easy for you to cut the axis off.) See additional edits.